# How to set HttpOnly and secure flag for domain controller project(not standalone) deploying in HA mode? I'm using wildfly 20

Tags: wildfly, domaincontroller

I'm using wildfly 20.If I set HttpOnly and secure flags in web.xml file it works in standalone project not with domain controller project. Please help with this

I tried with this

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

But in domain contrller project it's not working(not able to login)

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to the following directory within your Infogix server:
   /wildfly//configuration
    refers to the JVM/config name chosen during installation. This is commonly IA, II, IV, ER or default.
2. Edit the standalone-full-ha.xml file
3. Add the following property to the single-sign-on tag within the "default-host" host tag:
   http-only="true" secure="true"
   And add the following line within the undertow subsystem's default servlet container:

   For example, the relevant snippet of the undertow subsystem with both changes would look similar to this:

   ...

4)Restart Wildfly

5)If you have multiple JVMs, then these steps will need to be repeated for each JVM directory. (https://customer.precisely.com/s/article/Enabling-http-only-and-secure-cookies-within-Wildfly-360027239874?language=en_US)

6. If still not able to login check content-security-policy